# Python: Keeping text files synced on client and server using as little data as possible

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm about to build a project, in which the client device shows little random messages, that are continually edited on a server, accessible through a simple website. So far so good...
Programming the client, choosing a random file, and displaying the text, isn't such a big deal, as well as the server and writing the files to a folder on the server. But, the client should be portable, with a cheap SIM Card (500MB monthly data) I never did something like this, so how can I keep the files synchronized on the client and server? Or would it be better to use an SQL database?

Thanks in advance

For better understanding, I attached an image of how I imagined the project.

[Project overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVyPy.jpg)

Comment: Have you looked at rsync? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories-on-a-vps

Comment: Do old files ever go away?  Or only new ones are added?  If old ones are deleted, are they always deleted in the order they were added?  Or can they be deleted randomly?  Do messages ever change once they are added?

Comment: Actually that's a very easy and convenient way. Thanks

Comment: @little_birdie The files are picked randomly and than also deleted in the "random" order, after use. The files/messages arent going to be changed. But rsync is exactly what I need, II think

Comment: Sure, if you are able to use rsync that will do all the work for you of making sure the client has the same files as the server and it's very efficient with bandwidth.  But if the client only displays a message once and then deletes it (which is I think what you are saying), that won't work with rsync because it'll just see that the file is missing and fetch it from the server again, if the server still has it.

Comment: If the client is only going to display a message once ever, then why don't you have the client connect to the server each time it needs a new message and have the server choose the message?  But you'll need a way to keep track of what messages each client saw already.

Comment: Oh, I didnt know, that rsync only works one-way. Youre right, managing the displayed message on the server would be better.